# Two divs side by side: first fixed-width, second stretch-to-fit

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a layout where I have two `div`s side-by-side. The first `div` should be as wide as its content requires it to be. The second `div` should stretch to fill up the remaining space. The markup will look something like this:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">fixed width</div>
    <div id="d3">stretching</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that either both `div`s are just as wide as their content and do not stretch to fill the entire horizontal space, or that (e.g. when using `display: table` on `d1` and `display: table-cell` on `d2` and `d3`) both `div`s stretch.

How can I fix the width of `d2` and stretch `d3` to fill up the remaining space? Note that the width of `d2` is not known, so I cannot specify it in pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that should do it :

```
#d1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#d2, #d3 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

#d2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#d3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can try it [here](http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/wGpbn)

Comment: Well the `div` can contain either 'dog' or 'someverylongword'. In both cases, it should be just wide enough to contain the text. It should not stretch.