# Second div to fit in the space

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs

- Div 1 on the left
- Div 2 on the right to fill the space left from Div 1
- There should be 100px space between eachother.

The problem if I cannot insert the space between each other with `margin-left: 100px;` on `d3`. How can I achieve this?

REF: [Two divs side by side: first fixed-width, second stretch-to-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792288/two-divs-side-by-side-first-fixed-width-second-stretch-to-fit)

Thanks

**CSS**

```
   #d1 {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #d2, #d3 {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 2px 6px;
    }

    #d2 {
      background-color: #eee;
      white-space: nowrap;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }

    #d3 {
      background-color: #ccc;
      margin-left: 100px; /* This doesn't work*/
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="d1">
        <div id="d2">This is a content</div>
        <div id="d3">stretching</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `#d3` is as wide as `#d1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin will not be affected for using `display: table-cell;`

Check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/margin)

So if you can use `border-collapse:separate` in the parent div if div has `display: table;`

Check [DEMO -jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/streetcoder/SLps9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/td7k4/4/). 
I was able to get the 100px margin between the two divs. I put it on the right of the div `d2` but you could probably put it on `d3`. I also gave `d2` a `max-width` of `100%` but still trying to figure out `d3`